# What are all of D.va's Korean voice lines?

Tags: overwatch

I just mainly want to know the ones she uses the most.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. As you have probably noticed, your post has received some downvotes. The reason being that primarily, this question does not provide much information, or research effort.

Answer (score 3):

The [Overwatch wiki](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/D.Va/Quotes) has a list of all of the quotes each character uses, in each situation, as well as alternate lines used when they are wearing different skins or in different games/events. E.g.:

> First Spawn
>
> - "I play to win!"
>
> Mid-game Swap
>
> - "D.Va online."
> - "D.Va reporting in!" (Officer skin)

Additionally, the wiki also uses tooltips (hover over an underlined quote with you cursor) to translate some of the non-english quotes the characters may use. E.g.:

> Respawning
>
> - "I'm too young to die!"
> - "I'm back in the fight!"
> - "Ha! 짜증나!" ["Jah Jin Nah" translates to "How Frustrating!"]